# How to display no result in the page if no list is added?

Tags: android, list, listview

In my upper right corner of my activity, it has a + `button` used to add new list. For first time user, I want the page display **no result** if there are no list. If it has list added, it will shows the list and **no result* will dismiss. Can someone tell me how to achieve this ?

I know how to create list/listView, just want to know how to make the **no result*  disappeared if new list is added. Do I need to use two `xml` and two different pages ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**listModel** is my model in which I have added my data to be fetched, so check that model and simply set the visibility accordingly to that.

```
if (listModel.size() == 0) {
                txtNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lstView.setVisibility(View.GONE);           
            }
            else {
                txtNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lstView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: where should I put the txtNoData ? inside my customBaseadapter?

Comment: you can declare it in getview, for more info, please visit this link: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: Did the link you gave will display no result when
listView.size equal to o ?

Comment: but you do not have to add nodata to your adapter, as such you have to add it to your java class.

Comment: I saw your answer, as it has textView right ? The textView should declare at Activity or adapter?

Comment: yup exactly. It should be declared in your activity and that reason it will be changed according to your arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

In your layout, add TextView has Text "No Result" has visibility is invisible and ListView for render data visible.

In you activity/fragment, check your list item

If list item is null or empty, textView.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)

Else set visible for listView. listView.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking a TextView and a ListView inside a RelativeLayout.
set textView's visibility to gone.
and listView's visibility to visible

and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

you may use Visibility parametr, in your XML must be list and **no result*(no result visibility must be gone) if list not empty - do nothing, if list is empty - do View.Visible on **no result*